# $z^c = e^{c \log z}$ vs. $z^c = e^{\log z^c}$ and the domain of equality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, definition

Definition of $x^r$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r\in \mathbb{Q^c}$ makes sense if we define it as a limit of $x^{r_n}$ for a sequence ${\{r_n}\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ for $\lim_{\infty} r_n=r$. And the reasons are that $x^r$ is a continuous function of $r$ and both $\mathbb{Q}$ and \mathbb{Q^c} are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Churchill's book defines $z^c = e^{c \log z}$ because

> [it] provides a consistent definition of $z^c$ in the sense that it is
>   already known to be valid when $c =n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c =
>  \dfrac{1}{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Also the book defines $\log z$ based on $z = e^{\log z}$. So, my Question 1. is that isn't it more reasonable to to define $z^c = e^{\log z^c}$ since

1- "Defining" a **number** (or a set of numbers) makes sense **only** if it indicates **the** value of it and we can't define whatever we want;

2- Extending from $c =n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c = \dfrac{1}{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to any $c \in \mathbb{C}$ doesn't seem logical because $\mathbb{C}$ is much "larger" set [I mean it may not be possible uniquely extrapolate to $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{N} \cup {\{\frac1n}\}$] and it may result in different extensions.

3- Though may(?)     $e^{\log z^c}=e^{c \log z}$ but $\log z^c \ne c \log z$ in general even for $c \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

And, Question 2. Is it possible $e^{c \log z} \ne e^{\log z^c}$ for some pair $(z,c)$?

Comment: Isn't $z^c:=\mathrm{e}^{\log z^c}$ circular?

Comment: What did you try? With the usual principal value,
$$
\log((-i)^2)=i \pi \ne -i \pi = 2\log(-i)
$$

Comment: @user1337, what does it mean "circular"? I suggest $z^c:=\mathrm{e}^{\log z^c}$ because $z:=\mathrm{e}^{\log z} $..

Comment: it means defining $z^c$ in terms of $z^c$.

Comment: @user1337, Aha I got why the motivation for that definition, but still I can't find out answers for the questions I mentioned..

Comment: @user1337, esp. Q2. I don't know how to prove if $e^{c \log z}$ is uniquely equals to $z^c$? and the book's explanation is not rigorous (quoted one in OP).

Comment: Since $e^z$ is not injective on $\Bbb C$, the inverse function log is not well defined. You can take the principal value $log(r e^{i \theta})=log(r)+i \theta$ for $\theta\in]-\pi,\pi]$, (or any other semiclosed interval of length $2\pi$), and the formula $log(z^c)=c log(z)$ is only valid if both values $log(z^c)$ and $c log(z)$ are in the image of your log. In the example given by GEdgar $c log(z)=-\pi i$, which is outside the image of the principal log, but you can take $z=i$ and $c=5$, which will always fail, regardless of the choice of the logarithm.

Comment: However, since always $e^{log(z)}=z$, $$e^{log(z^c)}=e^{log(e^{c log(z)})}=e^{c log(z)}$$ so the definition is consistent.